# Re-arrange a Javascript array in a specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

Please note this not a duplicate Q.

I have a hard time figuring out the way to go from this JSON array,
which is one level array and we can have the path of each obj or element in the "path" property

```
[
  {
    "name" : "a-1",
    "path" : "a-1",
    "parent": ""
  },
  {
    "name" : "a-2",
    "path" : "a-1>a-2",
    "parent": "a-1"
  },
  {
    "name" : "a-3",
    "path" : "a-1>a-2>a-3",
    "parent": "a-2"
  },
  {
    "name" : "a-4",
    "path" : "a-1>a-4",
    "parent": "a-1"
  },
  {
    "name" : "b-1",
    "path" : "b-1",
    "parent": ""
  }
]
```

The final result should be as it follow,

```
[
  {
    "attr": {
      "name": "a-1",
      "path": "a-1",
      "parent": ""
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "a-2",
          "path": "a-1>a-2",
          "parent": "a-1"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "attr": {
              "name": "a-3",
              "path": "a-1>a-2>a-3",
              "parent": "a-2"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "a-4",
          "path": "a-1>a-4",
          "parent": "a-1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attr": {
      "name": "b-1",
      "path": "b-1",
      "parent": ""
    }
  }
]
```

I tried the to do so using the the parent with the Filter and find function

```
theOneLevelArray.filter((elt, idx, arr) => {
   let parent = arr.find(e => e.componentItemNumber === elt.parentItemNumber);
   if (!parent) return true;
          (parent.children = parent.children || []).push(elt);
});
```

I tried also using a loop then applying a reduce function after 'split(">")' the path element (the code is really messy for this method this is why I didn't paste)

Comment: It makes no sense to call `filter` and not use its return value.

Comment: Try recursion function.

Comment: Also, to solve your issue you don't need the `path` at all, just the `parent`

Comment: There's no [JSON](http://json.org) in the question/code.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it's a valid JSON. Read the link your suggested carefully :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's not [JSON](https://json.org). _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @Andreas happy learning than - What you're seeing above is a completely valid JSON format :)

Comment: Amine, I just find it a bit strange that you want to get `[{"attr":{},"children":[]}]` instead of creating a parent-child tree based on the *name* (given it's unique)

Comment: array is needed in exact format so it can much a component requirement that can't be modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple recursive approach:

```
function getNodes(parentName) {
  const mapNode = (node) => {
    const children = getNodes(node.name);
    return children.length > 0 ?
      { attr: node, children } :
      { attr: node };
  };

  return source
     .filter(n => n.parent === parentName)
     .map(mapNode);
}
```

Invocation: `getNodes('')`

It's assumed that `source` is the original array.

Comment: Why don't you pass `source` into the function?

Comment: We can pass it as parameter, yes. I just used it from outer closure. Actually, I tested this code in the node REPL, so, source was entered on the separate line.

Answer (score 1):

For using the given path, you could take an iterative approach by checking the given `path` and the temporary result.

This requires ordered data.

```js
var data = [{ name: "a-1", path: "a-1", parent: "" }, { name: "a-2", path: "a-1>a-2", parent: "a-1" }, { name: "a-3", path: "a-1>a-2>a-3", parent: "a-2" }, { name: "a-4", path: "a-1>a-4", parent: "a-1" }, { name: "b-1", path: "b-1", parent: "" }],
    tree = [];

data.forEach(function (object) {
    object.path.split('>').reduce(function (level, key) {
        var temp = level.find(({ attr: { name } }) => key === name);
        if (!temp) {
            temp = { attr: object, children: [] };
            level.push(temp);
        }
        return temp.children;
    }, tree);
});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach by using the `parent` property and a temporary obejct as reference to the object with the same name.

This works for unsorted data as well.

```js
var data = [{ name: "a-1", path: "a-1", parent: "" }, { name: "a-2", path: "a-1>a-2", parent: "a-1" }, { name: "a-3", path: "a-1>a-2>a-3", parent: "a-2" }, { name: "a-4", path: "a-1>a-4", parent: "a-1" }, { name: "b-1", path: "b-1", parent: "" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (attr) {
            var temp = { attr };
            if (o[attr.name] && o[attr.name].children) {
                temp.children = o[attr.name] && o[attr.name].children;
            }
            o[attr.name] = temp;
            if (attr.parent === root) {
                r.push(temp);
            } else {
                o[attr.parent] = o[attr.parent] || {};
                o[attr.parent].children = o[attr.parent].children || [];
                o[attr.parent].children.push(temp);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, '');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Code will give incorrect result if order of json will change. As per this code it always need json to be sorted in parent to child order.

Comment: right, it needs sorted parent child relation, as op has given.